# Java Message Formatter is not working

Tags: java, java-8, messageformat

I have String template

```
xxxxxxxx xxxxx-xx: [{0}] xxxxxxx xxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx [{1}] xxxxxx xxxx xxxxx'x xxxxx xxxxxx xxxx [{2}]
```

Even if I provide all the three arguments still not working

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = "xxxxxxxx xxxxx-xx: [{0}] xxxxxxx xxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx [{1}] xxxxxx xxxx xxxxx'x xxxxx xxxxxx xxxx [{2}]";

    System.out.println(MessageFormat.format(s,"1","2","3"));
}
```

The output is :

```
xxxxxxxx xxxxx-xx: [1] xxxxxxx xxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxx [2] xxxxxx xxxx xxxxxx xxxxx xxxxxx xxxx [{2}]
```

See output, Its outputting the `{2}` instead of `3`, I cannot find why it is not working. Is it a bug or I am missing something ?

Comment: See output . Its outputting the {2} instead of 3

Comment: Is the missing `'` in the output a typo or the actual output?

Comment: Its output , you can try

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Your problem is in the single quote `'` you have to use double `''` instead of one :

```
xxxxx''x
```

---

Read the documentation about single quote ([MessageFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/MessageFormat.html))

> Within a String, a pair of single quotes can be used to quote any
>   arbitrary characters except single quotes. For example, pattern string
>   "'{0}'" represents string "{0}", not a FormatElement. **A single quote
>   itself must be represented by doubled single quotes '' throughout a
>   String.** For example, pattern string "'{''}'" is interpreted as a
>   sequence of '{ (start of quoting and a left curly brace), '' (a single
>   quote), and }' (a right curly brace and end of quoting), not '{' and
>   '}' (quoted left and right curly braces): representing string "{'}",
>   not "{}".

Comment: Is this something provided in API doc?

Answer (score 4):

It's the apostrophe indeed, you need to escape it with another apostrophe, like : `''xxx`. Its in the doc btw:

> Within a String, '' (two single quotes ) represents a single quote.

Answer (score 3):

It's because you have `'` in your String. You need to escape it or you are missing one.